# Porque a função sumario está retornando undefined?

Tags: javascript, funções

Quando a função `console.log(contas.sumario())` da classe `CicloFinanceiro` é chamada, aparece os dois objetos como se era esperado e em seguida aparece undefined e não entendo o porquê.

`class Lancamento {
    constructor(nome = 'Genérico', valor = 0){
        this.nome = nome
        this.valor = valor
    }
}`

[image: Função que retorna undefined]

Comment: Não poste código como imagem, é péssimo para ler e pior ainda para tentar simular seu problema

Comment: O método `.forEach` retorna sempre `undefined`. Qual era o resultado que esperavas obter? Talvez queiras usar outro método mas só sabendo o que esperas podemos ajudar mais.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retorna `undefined` porque você está pedindo para o método `sumario()` retornar o retorno do método de array `forEach`, e este método por padrão executa uma função de callback para cada elemento do array e retorna sempre o valor de `undefined`.

Você pode ver isso através deste [link do developer mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), onde ele diz o seguinte:

> '' `forEach()` executa a a função callback uma vez para cada elemento do array – diferentemente de `map()` ou `reduce()`, ele sempre retorna o valor `undefined` e não é encadeável. O caso de uso típico é alterar o array no final do loop. ''.

Se você não quer ver o `undefined`, reescreva: `console.log(conta.sumario())` assim `conta.sumario();`